# Base change map $U\times_{X}X\rightarrow U\times_{Y}Y$

Tags: algebraic-geometry, category-theory

Let $X,Y$ be schemes. Let $X\rightarrow Y,X\rightarrow X, Y\rightarrow Y$ be morphisms of schemes. Why the morphism $U\times_{X}X\rightarrow U\times_{Y}Y$ is the base change of $X\rightarrow X\times_{Y}Y$ by $U\times_{Y}Y\rightarrow Y$?

Here is the diagram I try, where the triangle is commutative. But I found that $(U\times_{Y}Y)\times_{Y}(X\times_{Y}Y)=U\times_{Y}X\times_{Y}Y=U\times_{Y}X$, i.e. I can not obtain the desired $U\times_{X}X$. What mistakes do I make?
[image]

Here is the context in question, from Xinwen Zhu's paper *Affine Grassmannians and the geometric Satake in mixed characteristic* ([arXiv link](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1407.8519v3.pdf)):
[image]

Comment: What do you mean by "base change of $X\to X\times_YY$ by $U\times_YY\to Y$"? I thought that the base change of a morphism by another morphism is defined only when these morphisms have the same codomain.

Comment: @danneks: Yes, I have the same question. But my concrete context is complicated. I will give it with a screenshot.

Comment: I've taken the liberty of adding a link to the source document for you. Please don't forget that in the future. (Also, no need to keep deleting and reposting your question - you can [edit] things in to a suitable shape without deleting.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The diagrams are a bit more complicated than you're using here. First, we have a base change diagram defining $X\times_{Y,\sigma_Y} Y$ as follows:

$$\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
X\times_{Y,\sigma_Y} Y @>>> Y\\
@VVV @VV{\sigma_Y}V \\
X @>>> Y
\end{CD}$$

The morphism $X\to X\times_{Y,\sigma_Y} Y$ is induced by the identity morphism $X\to X$, the morphism $X\to Y$, and the universal property of the fiber product.

The diagram defining $U\times_{Y,\sigma_Y} Y$ is as follows:

$$\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
U\times_{Y,\sigma_Y}Y @>>> X\times_{Y,\sigma_Y} Y @>>> Y\\
@VVV @VVV @VV{\sigma_Y}V \\
U @>>> X @>>> Y
\end{CD}$$

Now base change the entire first diagram plus the induced morphism $X\to X\times_{Y,\sigma_Y} Y$ by the map $U\times_{Y,\sigma_Y} Y\to Y$ to get the claimed map.

Comment: Thanks, I get it! But I still have one question. It is clear that if $X\rightarrow X\times_{Y,\sigma_{Y}}Y$, then $U\times_{X,\sigma_{X}}X\rightarrow U\times_{Y,\sigma_{Y}}Y$ is an isomorphism. The converse is not necessarily true. Or pull-back reflects isomorphisms in the category of schemes?

Comment: I found a statement in Stack Project, Tag02VX, which implies that the base change functor  in question is faithful, since $U\times_{Y,\sigma_{Y}}Y\rightarrow X\times_{Y,\sigma_{Y}}Y$ is etale.

Comment: Ok, I have fixed this problem. But it seems that $U\times_{Y}Y\rightarrow Y$ should not be an etale cover. Clearly, it is etale, but not surjective.